# PowerSoft netclient on Proxmox

Tags: ups, systemctl, proxmox

I'm trying to run powersoft netclient (ever ups soft) on a node (kernel Linux 6.5.13-1-pve) inside proxmox ve 8.1.3. Installation goes smoothly, but trying to start powersoft.service displays error:

```
Mar 26 14:37:56 NODE3 (tService)\[1331729\]: powersoft.service: Failed to execute
/usr/share/powersoft/PowerSoftService: No such file or directory
```

UPS model is PowerLine 33 Green

I have tried to reinstall it and checked if pointed location exists '/usr/share/powersoft/PowerSoftService'; neither of it worked - the location indeed exists and have execution permission on root.